# Combine elements from two arrays into subarrays in a third array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm starting with two equal-length arrays, and I'd like to create a new array made up of sub arrays, each of which are made from combining elements at each index of both arrays. Here is what I mean:

```
// the 2 initial arrays:
var arr1 = ["Quote1", "Quote2", "Quote3"];
var arr2 = ["Author1", "Author2", "Author3"];

// the output I need to achieve:
[ ["Quote1", "Author1"], ["Quote2", "Author2"], ["Quote3", "Author3"] ];
```

The problem is that my code produces the following output to the `console.log`:

```
Array [ Array[2], Array[2], Array[2] ]
```

The problematic output I'm getting doesn't show the actual values of each subarray, it only shows the length of each subarray.

Here is my code:

```
var quotesArr = ["Quote 1", "Quote 2", "Quote 3"];

var authorsArr = ["Author 1", "Author 2", "Author 3"];

var quoteMeetsAuthor = [];

var quotesAndAuthors = [];


function combineArrays(quotes,authors) {
  if (quotes.length != authors.length) {
    console.log("Danger Will Robinson!");
    return "Danger Will Robinson!";
  }

  for (i=0; i<quotes.length; i++) {
    quoteMeetsAuthor.push(quotes[i]);
    quoteMeetsAuthor.push(authors[i]);
    quotesAndAuthors.push(quoteMeetsAuthor);
    quoteMeetsAuthor = [];
  }
  console.log(quotesAndAuthors);
  return quotesAndAuthors;
}

combineArrays(quotesArr, authorsArr);
```

Can anyone offer advice?

**Edit**: I'd like to solve this using vanilla javascript.

Comment: google zip javascript arrays. Many libraries (lodash, underscore, etc) implement that function, Ramda is my favorite.

Comment: The code looks fine, and the output in FireFox is correct aswell.

Comment: Your code works. Your console doesn't display the array like you want. Use another browser which has a console which behaves like you want. Or stringify the array.

Comment: Hi @Kenney - the output in my firefox console reads:

`Array [ Array[2], Array[2], Array[2] ]`, not, `[ ["Quote1", "Author1"], ["Quote2", "Author2"], ["Quote3", "Author3"] ]`. I'm after the second output, but I only get the first output.

Comment: In mine it reads `[["Quote 1", "Author 1"], ["Quote 2", "Author 2"], ["Quote 3", "Author 3"]]
[["Quote 1", "Author 1"], ["Quote 2", "Author 2"], ["Quote 3", "Author 3"]]`.... (45.0.1).

Comment: @BrianZ that's correct though, it is indeed and array of arrays.  See what happens when you log `quotesAndAuthors[0]`.  See if you get `["Quote1", "Author1"]`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code works. The only problem is that the developer tools of the OP don't behave like he expected.

Comment: Thanks @ryanyuyu - i checked that and indeed get the expected result at that index place. What browser console are you using? I get the same results as I've reported above in both fire fox dev edition and chrome.

Comment: @BrianZ I also see the same output you see.  The problem is that the browser console is free to represent the object however it wants to.  I think your spec is missing something.  Because your current output and the expected output are exactly the same.  Just represented on the screen differently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with to solve your issue.  Also, try using alert() instead of console.log() to see the true results.  console.log() sometimes does not display everything, and so you need to expand some of what it stores:

```
var arr1 = ["Quote1", "Quote2", "Quote3"];
var arr2 = ["Author1", "Author2", "Author3"];

// the output I need to achieve:
//[ ["Quote1", "Author1"], ["Quote2", "Author2"], ["Quote3", "Author3"] ];

var newArr = [[],[],[]];

for(var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
    newArr[i].push(arr1[i]);
    newArr[i].push(arr2[i]);
}

alert(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks @paulg, but I need to programmatically scale this up for my actual need (ie - way more than 3 elements in each initial array), so hard coding the number of subarrays I'm after won't work.

Comment: But you were right in suggesting to use alert() -- the output from that was indeed what I expected, thanks!